# Missing connections between line and points

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, point, line, spatial-join

I have two shapefiles

1. [line layer](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Fy2t14FMfaAGNQl7c_csi_tt3z52bM1d?usp=sharing) (Blue color)
2. [points layer](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Fy2t14FMfaAGNQl7c_csi_tt3z52bM1d?usp=sharing) which represents houses (Green color))

I am trying to `connect line with points` (houses). For that, I used [closestSegmentWithContext](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#aaa0c911cb37cc33dd024662ec314fdae) as shown in the below script of `PyQGIS.

**Problem I am facing:** The PyQGIS script connects only few points. There is no connecting line between points and line at some points as shown with red crosses in below image.

[image]

**PyQGIS script:**

```
roadlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Line')[0]
addrlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Point')[0]

#List all features
adresses = [f for f in addrlyr.getFeatures()]
roads = [f for f in roadlyr.getFeatures()] 

##Create vector layer
#vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs={}" + "&field=id:integer""&field=distance:double(20,2)&index=yes".format(roadlyr.crs().authid()), "myLayer", "memory")

uri = "LineString?crs={}:"  + "&field=id:integer""&field=distance&index=yes" # Generate Conducting_equipment_mrid

vl = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                      'Connections',
                      'memory')

provider = vl.dataProvider()

feats = []
for adress in adresses:
    a = min([road.geometry().closestSegmentWithContext(adress.geometry().asPoint()) for road in roads], key=lambda x: x[0]) #For each road find closest address
    gLine = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(adress.geometry().asPoint()), QgsPoint(a[1])])
  
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(gLine)
    f.setAttributes([adresses.index(adress),f.geometry().length()])
    
    feats.append(f)
    provider.addFeature(f)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Comment: Are they MultiPoints? This `addrlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('point')[0]
` should be `addrlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Point')[0]`. Your code is working for me

Comment: Yes. There are multiple points and lines. Sorry the ('Point') in the addrlyr was typo mistake and I updated in the question.

Comment: The data shapes are also attached in the question.

Comment: Not multiple points, multipart geometry. You misunderstand, see https://www.google.com/search?q=multipoint+gis&safe=off&client=firefox-b-e&hl=sv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis4ITz5cDtAhUk-yoKHRQvATEQ_AUoAXoECAgQAw&biw=1920&bih=903#imgrc=cT2J3Vf2YD_OKM . One point can consist of 10 parts/points so when you select one, 9 other also get selected

Comment: I dont think they are multipart geometry. The data points are like this in the attribute table : https://ibb.co/c6Yf16Z

Comment: what is the value of `a` and `gLine` for the ones that don't work?

Comment: @IanTurton. If I undertand it well, the values in the attribute table looks like this: https://ibb.co/QXr44hk . The notable thing here is,the distance values are zero for the ones that don,t work.

Comment: so `gLine` is a point not a line?

Comment: @IanTurton. `gLine` creates a new LineString geometry from a list of QgsPoint points with `QgsGeometry.fromPolyline` class.

Comment: [`fromPolyline`](https://qgis.org/api/qgsgeometry_8cpp_source.html#l00184) calls `make_unique` on it's input, so if the two points are the same I think you will get a Point not a Line back.

Comment: @Ian Turton. Thank you for the nice suggestion. What should I change in the above code (question)?. Can you add the required thing in the code or post your suggestions in answer of this question?. The data sample (shapefiles) and the PyQGIS script are both available in question.